# How to export an image from Photoshop with the multiply effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, export, photoshop-effects, blend-modes

I have a design in Photoshop with two images with the multiply effect. This effect is not possible in all browsers with Javascript/CSS3, so I decided to export the images with the effect from Photoshop.

I copied the layer of the image with the multiply effect. Then I exported this. But when I put it in browser, the multiply effect is gone.

What is the correct way to export images with multiply?

Comment: Hi Dvex, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. I went ahead and cleaned up your language a bit and added some tags. Is I changed anything beyond your intention, feel free to [edit] again. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a new layer that is black and add a mask to it
2. Paste your image into the mask (alt+click the mask) and invert it

All the white is now masked out of your image, while black is solid, similar to multiply

3. Save for web as 24 bit PNG with transparency
4. Use ImageAlpha if you want to save it at a smaller size

It looks a bit dark compared to "real" multiply transparency, but is OK in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to use the multiply layer effect without using CSS then you will have to save as a flattened image and not just saving the individual layer.

So if Layer 2 has the multiply blending mode which goes over Layer 1. Then you will need to save the image with both Layer 1 & 2 showing.